# Which filesystem should I use for camera and linux distro?

Tags: boot, files, filesystem, camera, copy

My SD card is formatted to msdos filesystem but I have a 5.7 GB file and Nautilus messages that the size is too big so it can't be copied to the card.
I also want to use the card in my camera, but I want to put my linux distro on it too.

Comment: exFAT might work, but it really depends on what the camera supports, which might be only classic FAT32.

Comment: ohh is it possible to make 2 partitions on sd cards?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make 2 partitions on SD cards. You can use **gparted** to do it. But I am not sure that the camera can manage it. Test it: if it works, fine, otherwise, let the camera format the card. That way you should get something that works with the camera. Let us hope that it is useful enough. (But it might format to FAT32, with the 4 GB file size limit.)